# Python: __eq__(self, other): len(self.sensor_data) ok, but len(other.senor_data) => AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

I have a class named `CAN_MSG` for which I want to define the `__eq__`  method so that I can check two classes for equality.

Input_CAN_Sorter.py:

```
class CAN_MSG:
    def __init__(self, first_sensor_id, timestamp, sensor_data):
        self.first_sensor_id = first_sensor_id
        self.sensor_data = sensor_data
        self.timestamp = timestamp

    def __eq__(self, other):
        result = self.first_sensor_id == other.first_sensor_id
        n = len(self.sensor_data)  # no Error
        i = len(other.senor_data)  # AttributeError: 'CAN_MSG' object has no attribute 'senor_data'.
        result = result and len(self.sensor_data) == len(other.senor_data)

        for i in range(len(self.sensor_data)):
            result = result and self.sensor_data[i] == other.senor_data[i]

        result = result and self.timestamp == other.timestamp
        return result
```

The class has a list of ints called sensor_data. When I compare using  `__eq__(self, other):`
There is no problem with `len(self.sensor_data)`, but with `len(other.sensor_data)`  I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'CAN_MSG' object has no attribute 'senor_data'.

I don't understand why I can access `self.sensor_data` but not `other.sensor_data`.

test.py:

```
from Input_CAN_Sorter import CAN_MSG

list_temp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list_temp2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

CAN_MSG_1 = CAN_MSG(1, "TIME", list_temp)
CAN_MSG_2 = CAN_MSG(1, "TIME", list_temp2)


if CAN_MSG_1 == CAN_MSG_2:
    print("=")
```

In C++ I would have done a check for the class type before and maybe a cast afterwards so that the compiler knows for sure that it is the same class, but in Python this is not possible/necessary if I understand correctly.

Probably this is a completely stupid mistake but I'm not 100% familiar with Python and can't come up with a reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled your variable name.

> AttributeError: 'CAN_MSG' object has no attribute '**senor**_data'.

```
i = len(other.senor_data)
```

You meant to write:

```
i = len(other.sensor_data)
```

Comment: Okay, I'm ultra embarrassed that I didn't see that. But thanks for pointing out. Of course the whole thing works now. Thanks

Comment: It's okay, we all make small mistakes like this and especially in new languages.